# TestNG data provider with folder contents using lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8, testng, testng-dataprovider

I want to give a list of file names through a TestNG data provider, so the test can load each file.

```
Object[][] result = Files.list(Paths.get("tst/resources/json"))
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .map(fileName -> new Object[] { fileName })
            .toArray(Object[][]::new);
```

I've got to the point where I can build the Object[][] from the folder contents, but TestNG throws exception:

```
org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
Data provider mismatch
Method: testFBTinka11InterpretJson([Parameter{index=0, 
type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
Arguments: [(sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath$WindowsPathWithAttributes)tst\resources\json\admin.json]

at org.testng.internal.reflect.DataProviderMethodMatcher.getConformingArguments(DataProviderMethodMatcher.java:52)
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that your `@Test` method which is using your data provider is accepting only file names as a `String` but your data provider is actually providing it with a `File` object and that is where its breaking.

You have two options:

1. You change your `@Test` method to accept a `File` object instead of `String`. (or)
2. You change your data provider to start providing only absolute paths of `File` objects instead of `File` object. i.e., Change `.map(fileName -> new Object[] { fileName })` to `.map(fileName -> new Object[] { fileName.getAbsolutePath() })`

Comment: Thanks! It was actually a Path, but that was the issue with the code.
Updated: `.map(path -> new Object[] { path.toString() })`